# ng-options is not displayed all the time in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I have a small problem when I load my page. Sometimes, my `ng-options` has blank values. I don't understand why. I can load the page 10 times without problem, but I can load the page with blank values.

However, JSON returned is not blank. Always the same result :

SERVICE :

```
myApp.factory('GenericService', function ($http, $q) {
    var data;

    function getDataIfNeeded(the_action) {

        the_action = the_action || 'default';

        if (data !== undefined) {
            return $q.when(data);
        }

        return $http({
            url: "php/functions.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: { 
                action: the_action
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            data = response.data;
            return data;
        });
    }

    return {
        getData: getDataIfNeeded
    };
});
```

CONTROLLER :

```
GenericService.getData("get_leaders").then(function (data) {
  $scope.leaders = data;
});

...

GenericService.getData("get_experts_ux").then(function (data) {
  $scope.experts_ux = data;
});
```

JSON :

```
   [
      {"lead_technique_id":1,"lead_technique_name":"Delphine ____"},
      {"lead_technique_id":2,"lead_technique_name":"Thierry ____"}
   ]
```

HTML :

```
     <select ng-model="newProject.lead_technique_id" ng-options="leader.lead_technique_id as leader.lead_technique_name for leader in leaders" required></select>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you retrieve the JSON ? Is it with a call to $http or $ressource ? If so, it is possible that you load the page before the promise is resolved, thus the blank options...

Comment: Check my update please I use $http

Comment: @Steffi - Post your controller code where you make the call

Comment: I think it's because I don't use an array for `data`. I create this service because, I use this for several queries.

Comment: it would be good if you post your controller and service code here.

Comment: If the last image that you posted is what you see when the "ng-options are not displayed" then I think what your problem really is, is that the names are not populated in your object.  I see that the ng-options ARE displayed, but just with no labels